# What is the equivalent of "X window system" in Microsoft Windows?

Tags: windows, desktop-environments

We all know **Linux/Unix** uses **X window** system for Graphical User Interface.

Can anyone tell me what system does **MS Windows** use for Graphical User Interface?

Comment: Do you mean Microsoft Windows by "Window"?

Comment: Yes I mean Microsoft window

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows provides two libraries for applications: GDI and USER.  GDI handles primitives for drawing to the screen ( or other devices, like printers ), and USER provides more high level features such as windows.  In Windows NT 3.1-3.51, they were implemented in csrss.exe, then in NT 4 the implementation was moved to win32k.sys to avoid context switching when a program made those calls.